# Issue in DB2 Express-C Connection while sharing a database over LAN from Java

Tags: java, 64-bit, db2

I have installed DB2 Express-C 9.7.5. It was installed on a Windows 7 (64-bit) machine and I created a database, TESTXA. The connection mechanism used in my application is:

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://ABCCOMPUTER:50000/TESTXA", db2UserName, db2PassWord);
```

The connection successfully created on ABCCOMPUTER with the above Java code. But when I use the same Java code to create a DB2 connection from another system over LAN, for example, XYZCOMPUTER (Windows 7 machine) with the same db2UserName/db2PassWord, throws an exception:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=USER.XA4APP, DRIVER=3.57.82
Which indicates "Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: User ID or Password invalid."
```

In my application, I need to create a database in DB2 which can be accessed from other systems on a LAN. What should be looked into on XYZCOMPUTER to resolve this issue?

(FYI: This is no issue of DB2 database sharing in Windows XP machines. The above mechanism works properly.)

Comment: This might be helpful. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000381.html

Comment: I don't think its an issue of trust_clntauth parameter setting, since I am providing the correct user/password in connection url.

Comment: Did you create the `db2UserName` account on the XYZCOMPUTER machine?  Or, is this account a Windows domain account?  If so, is XYZCOMPUTER a member of the same domain as ABCCOMPUTER?

Comment: No. I have not created such account on XYZCOMPUTER machin. Yes both computer are the member of the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

This should be no issue of Java [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity). It must be the case of a Windows 7 security issue because the DB2 type 4 driver uses the same format of the connection string whether it's a case of your own system or a remote system. You can try to run your application/tool as 'Run as Administrator'.